# 저 영화는 아주 슬퍼요/슬펐어요. 그래서 많이 울었어요

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, tense

1. 저 영화는 아주 **슬퍼요**. 그래서 많이 울었어요.
2. 저 영화는 아주 **슬펐어요**. 그래서 많이 울었어요.

Are both sentences correct? If so, is there any difference in meaning between #1 and #2?

Comment: `그래서 많이 울었어요` makes #1, #2 sentences as past sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they are both correct, and I reckon the difference in meaning is similar to the difference between "The film is very sad" and "The film was very sad" in English - the first statement is a more general description of the film, and the second focuses more on your experience of the film at a given time.

However, because your experience can change, it could make sense to say something like

> 나이 어렸을때 그 영화는 아주 슬펐지만 이제는 즐거워요.
>   When I was younger, the movie was very sad but now it is fun

In that case, saying 나이 어렸을때 그 영화는 아주 슬프지만 wouldn't sound so good, because 슬프지만 doesn't have the sense of focusing on a particular time.